# Access MEF part from ASP MVC 4 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

We are using ASP MVC 4 to build a web application.
We have a shared part which hold the logic that tell the rest of the application if the current request is a "test" request. We do it in order for our end-to-end testing will not disrupt our normal site activity.

On the controllers we simply get the interface of that part in the ctor and we have access to it.

The problem is how to allow the views to access it also.
For once, we have a partial view that we put in our _Layout.cshtml file that add google analytics code, if we are under test we do not want to emit that code.

Is there a clean way to allow razor views access to MEF parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to directly do an import within a view; I usually use the Import attributes and those can't be used in the view. You could do the composition in another class and then create a reference to that class within the view, but I don't know that you could call that 'clean'.

If I understand your specific case, it seems like it would be easier to address this in the action that returns the partial view that has the Google Analytics business. When the MEF part imported by the controller says the request is a 'test' request, the action would just return a blank view.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I don't put it in an action is because it should happen in all actions of all the controllers. As the DRY principle I don't want to repeat it in every action. Thank you

Comment: In that case, maybe a custom view engine that knows about your MEF part would work well.